# Update MacOS notification center menu bar icon after change 'Do Not Disturb' setting programmatically

Tags: macos, icons, menubar, notificationcenter

I have implemented the function of "Enable/Disable MacOS Notification Center's Do Not Disturb" on Mac programmatically.

Environment: macOS Mojave 10.14.6, Xcode 11.3.1.

Here is my code(Objective-C):

```
- (void)setDoNotDisturbEnabled:(BOOL)flag{
    CFStringRef appID = CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui");
    
    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("doNotDisturb"),
                          (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)([NSNumber numberWithBool:flag]),
                          appID,
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
    
    if(flag){
        CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("doNotDisturbDate"),
                              (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)([NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]),
                              appID,
                              kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                              kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
    }else{
        CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("doNotDisturbDate"),
                              NULL,
                              appID,
                              kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                              kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
    }
    
    [[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.notificationcenterui"] firstObject] forceTerminate];
}
```

When I pass "YES" to the method, the icon on the menu bar dims and after clicking it, I can see the Do Not Disturb switch is on.

When I pass "NO" to the method, the Do Not Disturb switch is off, but the dimmed icon does not restore to normal state.

A little flaw, if anyone can help me fix it, that will be perfect.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419207/turn-do-not-disturb-on-or-off-in-an-applescript-app-macos-catalina/419215#419215